# How do I reduce the inner padding around the text within an Android button object?

Tags: java, android, xml, mobile, user-interface

[image: Example buttons]

So, at the moment I have a button which looks like the first image above. How do I reduce the padding around the text inside the button itself (To look more like the second image)?

Layout width and height is set as:

```
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

The custom style shape has parameters"

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">
```

With the rest just being color attributes and radii values.

Just to make it clear, I want the frame of the button to hug the "Login" text closer.

All help and feedback is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: android:padding="10dp reduce 10 dp to 5dp

Comment: That relates to the outer padding of the Button. I'm referring to the internal padding of "login" and its container. Thanks though.

Comment: This helped me - https://stackoverflow.com/a/19227057/3325759 (author - @StinePike)
From the answer - Add `android:includeFontPadding="false"`

Comment: overriding the padding works for me. textView.setPadding(0,0,0,0);

Comment: Put 
    android:minHeight="0dp"
    android:minWidth="0dp"
in the button. This should work..

Comment: Right question, wrong answer. This does not work. android:minHeight="0dp"
android:minWidth="0dp"
works. That said your answer does remove a tiny tiny sliver, but the min height/width is the clear winner.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

It took me forever to find this but the "padding" around the text in a button isn't really padding at all. The default Widget.Button style includes a `minHeight` property. Changing `minHeight` on the button will allow you to adjust padding as expected.

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/test"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:minHeight="40dip"/>


<style name="Widget.Holo.Button" parent="Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_holo_dark</item>
    <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
    <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
</style>
```

Comment: I was facing a similar problem with the width. Setting android:minWidth="0dp" worked, but then on buttons with long text, I required android:paddingRight and android:paddingLeft to be set to prevent poor layout.

Comment: My Widget.Button has no minHeight (sdk28)

Comment: The property is on the theme button, not the parent "Widget.Button". If you are using a different theme than "holo" it may be in a different location. Here are the styles for "holo" https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/values/styles_holo.xml

Comment: it still has padding with `MaterialButton`, height has nothing to do, if you set `height` 48dp and `minHeight` 48dp you still will see padding, button background height will be smaller than 48dp

Comment: it's insets `android:insetTop="0dp" android:insetBottom="0dp"`, then it will finally remove padding and background button height will be 48dp

Answer (score 23):

In the Material Components Library, the `MaterialButton` has a default style with `insetBottom` and `insetTop` with a value of `6dp`.

You can change them in the layout:

```
  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
      android:insetTop="0dp"
      android:insetBottom="0dp"
      ../>
```

or in a style:

```
 <style name="Button_no_insets" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button"..>
    <item name="android:insetTop">0dp</item>
    <item name="android:insetBottom">0dp</item>
 </style>
```

[image][image]

Answer (score 4):

try this in your custom shape.xml file

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle"
android:paddingLeft="10dp"
android:paddingRight="10dp"
android:paddingTop="1dp"
android:padding="1dp">
```

also you can make change in your button's xml

```
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
```

Comment: This doesn't work at all if you read what the original question is asking

Answer (score 2):

If you want a smaller top and bottom padding, use this:

```
 android:paddingTop="2dp"
 android:paddingBottom="2dp"
```

Comment: That's for the padding outside the button. The effect I'm after is to get the Button frame to hug the "Login" text closer. Thanks.

Comment: That is already the inner padding of the button. You may need to check if you have added lines like `android:padding` or `android:layout_margin"` in the parent views of `<shape />`.

Answer (score 2):

For me, need to set all below for the button property

```
minWidth 
minHeight
paddingHorizontal
paddingVertical
layout wrap_content


  android:paddingVertical="0dp"
  android:paddingHorizontal="0dp"
  android:minHeight="0dp"
  android:minWidth="0dp"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

this will remove all spaces between text and border of button and border(if used) will be around the text without any space.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

**Update**: If you want to use **Material Button**: >

You can use style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton" attribute, set insetTop & insetBottom to 0dp. Also set  app:cornerRadius="0dp" to get same result of my given picture.

```
  <com.google.android.material.button.MaterialButton
        android:id="@+id/btnAddMorePassenger"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/primary_variant"
        android:insetTop="0dp"
        android:insetBottom="0dp"
        android:text="@string/add_passenger"
        android:textColor="@color/light"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:cornerRadius="0dp"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_profile_24dp"
        app:iconGravity="textStart"
        app:iconTint="@color/light"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
        tools:visibility="visible" />
```

You can use **Borderless** style in **AppCompatButton** like below. Also use background color your preferred.

> Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored

Button code

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
        android:id="@+id/button_visa_next"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/spacing_normal"
        android:text="@string/next"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Output:

[image]