# Buttons with minimal padding (in XML)

Tags: android, xml

I am making an image processing test environment for my personal use only. I want to have a lot of buttons on screen at the same time - unfortunately the screen is becoming rather crowded. It would be much better if I could reduce the amount of padding on each side of the text within my buttons (it doesn't matter if the end result is a bit ugly), but am not sure of the best way to do this. Could I do it via the use of a style setting?

A typical button in my app currently looks like this:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/but_startstoprec"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/but_histogram"
    android:layout_below="@+id/but_histogram"
    android:text="Rec/Stp" />
```

Comment: Yes, or by using dimens files (just to have different paddings for different resolutions). You can combine the style and the dimens technique, of course, for an increased flexibility.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16394252/how-do-i-reduce-the-inner-padding-around-the-text-within-an-android-button-objec could answer your question.

Comment: @ojs: Perfect, android:minWidth="0dip" does the trick. Put it as an answer and I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the following setting

```
<Button
    ...
    android:padding="0dp"
    ...
```

as well as setting minimum width and height of button elements to 0, not to limit the minimum button size:

```
<Button
    ... 
    android:minHeight="0dp" 
    android:minWidth="0dp" 
    ...
```

Best.