# Centering large text inside a button in Android not working

Tags: android, android-layout, button, textview, android-button

I need to center a large digit inside a `Button`, but it is always displayed shifted down. Please see the image:

[image]

**My activity_main.xml file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:textSize="490sp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="8" />
</LinearLayout>
```

If I set some smaller text size — it is centered correctly.
Also, if I use `ImageButton` with `android:scaleType="center"`, the image is centered perfectly. But I need to center text.

Could you please help, how to solve this problem?

Definitely it is a Android bug. Probably there is some class or workaround.

Comment: Please show the full layout. Your button is constrained by the parent and can't grow tall enough to fit the text. Either change the parent to allow for a larger child, or reduce the text size.

Comment: I tried different layouts — it is always shifted down with large text. You can create a new simple project and try to put some large text inside a button. With TextView same problem. Probably need to implement some special class for this centering, but where to find it.

Comment: That's not the full layout, your LinearLayout may still be constrained by its parent. Please post the full XML layout.

Comment: I think fill_parent is making problem. can you try . button's width and height wrap_content
`<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="80sp" />`

Comment: Vivart, I've tried — nothing changed. Francesc, please see, I've updated my post. It is just a blank project with one button.

Comment: i suggest make 450sp..

Answer (score 1):

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

   <Button 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:gravity="center" 
        android:text="8" 
        android:textSize="80sp" />
```

So you are using fill_parent as parameter in bottom and also linearlayout, so I guess what might happen is it dosen't have enough space for the linearlayout and button, using wrap_content can let the bottom fit the text, not pendding on the layout weight and height

***** Update**

I saw you have already added

```
android:includeFontPadding="false"
```

If you really want to remove the space, try adding

```
android:layout_marginTop="-100dp"
```

into your button parameter.

Comment: OP, This is how you do it. If you're only concerned about the height you may only have to use `wrap_content` on the height. Either way, if you want, you can add some padding to give the content some room around the edges.

Comment: Nothing changed — still shifted down. Always there is some font padding. But how to get rid of it.

Comment: Ok. There's no reason that layout should give you any extra padding/margin. It has to be whatever layout is containing it. Can you edit your original post to include your app's container layouts (tool/appbar, any layout that references this one, etc.)?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<Button
    android:textSize="80sp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:includeFontPadding="false"
    android:text="8"
    android:paddingTop="1dp" />
```

Comment: Also shifted down.

Comment: post your full xml

Comment: I've tried to use only this layout with very large text — still shifted down.

Comment: Unfortunately for you, text will not compress if it is bigger than layout. The answer I gave you will work if layout is 90dp height and width. Solution, make button bigger or text smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Well,I suggest that if you make textsize 450sp it will give you perfect output

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <Button
        android:textSize="450sp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"

        android:text="8" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

Comment: Yes, I know this. But in my case the text size is critical. I have a grid with many such buttons, and I cannot reduce the font size more. I need just centered text on full button height (or even truncated top and bottom).

Comment: what do you mean with grid,what is the view exactly you trying to achive. share screen shot

Comment: Grid — I mean many linear layouts, but it is not important. The problem is visible on my main post (simple layout). Why if we set font size 490sp the digit is shifted down? The space is there. How to remove this hidden top padding. I'm now experimenting with minHeight: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19300777/2240880 — no resilts.

Comment: of course it is important..if you are trying to set multiple similer view, use it with recycler view and make it custom..and may be your issue will solve

Answer (score 0):

In your case the size of TextView defined is too big for the device you are testing. If you test the same layout with a higher resolution device you'll get your desired result.
All you have to do is define different textsizes for different resolution devices by defining different values for "textSize" in res/values-ldpi, values-mdpi, values-hdpi, values-xhdpi etc.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <Button
        android:textSize="@string/textSize"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:includeFontPadding="false"
        android:text="8" />
 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yes, I know this. But in my case the text size is critical. I have a grid with many such buttons, and I cannot reduce the font size more. I need just centered text on full button height (or even truncated top and bottom).

Comment: Use same textSize for all the items in your grid. Then the result will be as expected.

Answer (score 0):

There's one hack you use to achieve this: wrap the `Button` in a `FrameLayout` and use negative margins to center the `Button` as you see fit:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="41dp"
    android:layout_height="41dp">

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="-7dp"
        android:text="8"
        android:textSize="40dp"/>
</FrameLayout>
```

You'll find the `8` centered within the bounds of the `FrameLayout`. I've tested this method on multiple API's and the text remained centered on each.